# Can map() function be used with built-in functions?

Tags: python

I would like to know if it is possible to use the Python `map()` function with built in python functions, for example `map(built_in_function, iterable)`

Comment: yes.  why you don't try?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. For example:

`print(list(map(len, ["abb", "b", "cd"])))`